# Error with segue (unwind and regular) from modal view controller

Tags: swift, segue

I have an app that has the following navigation: 
(Navigation controller) -> Splash screen -> Home screen -> Modal VC1 -> Modal VC2 when the user is logged in. It goes Splash screen -> onboarding screens when the user is not logged in.

Modal VC2 has the log out button where I wish to unwind to the splash screen.

I've tried the unwind method to try to unwind to the first root controller:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueToSplash", sender: nil)
```

and I made sure that I had the correct identifier and the correct unwind IBAction in the right files:

(Will updated this with photos once I get enough reputation to do so)

but I get this error (where it says it does not recognize the identifier):

```
2018-12-28 21:56:22.171802-0800 test[23398:2685262] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<test.LogOutViewController: 0x7ff5ce6189c0>) has no segue with identifier 'unwindSegueToSplash''
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec3c1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e1da735 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113317568 -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
3   test                                0x000000010bc6f944 $S5test20LogOutViewControllerC03logC0yyypSgF + 580
4   test                                0x000000010bc6fa2c $S5test20LogOutViewControllerC03logC0yyypSgFTo + 188
5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113934ecb -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
6   UIKitCore                           0x00000001133700bd -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
7   UIKitCore                           0x00000001133703da -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
8   UIKitCore                           0x000000011336f31e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 583
9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001139700a4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2729
10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001139717a0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4080
11  UIKitCore                           0x000000011394f394 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113a245a9 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3054
13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113a271cb __handleEventQueueInternal + 5948
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eba1721 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eba1054 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 436
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eb9b63f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eb9ae11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011753a1dd GSEventRunModal + 62
19  UIKitCore                           0x000000011393381d UIApplicationMain + 140
20  test                                0x000000010bc6c077 main + 71
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110ca2575 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I get this same error when I have a regular segue to other pages in the app, too, not just unwind. I make sure that these segues have their identifiers properly written in the storyboard section.

I've also tried other methods I've seen where I pop to the root view controller, but it seems like my root view controller is the home screen rather than the splash screen (I'm assuming this has to do with them being modal view controllers?). It does segue here with no errors though.

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

and

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

I don't want to call 2 segues to get to the splash screen because I would like to unwind directly to the splash screen without the user seeing anything in between--how can I do that?

Comment: Can you share code if this is demo app ?

Comment: @MayurKarmur what code do you want to see?